# Inline css property backgroundImage is not load a images on build upload in subdirectory ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am making a production build and uploading on the server under the sub-directory. I am displaying a images using the inline CSS property backgroundImage. Its work on local is fine but after uploading to server sub-directory, images are not loaded because this path is not found.

Server sub-directory folder structure.

```
Home 
  -> admin (sub-directory under the home directory)
```

**React code::**

```
<div className="rct-quotes-slides h-100" style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`../assets/images/logo.png`) + ')' }} >
```

Comment: Are you store images in public folder or not....???

Comment: Refer this [Link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527#issuecomment-263051964)

Comment: @AnkitVerma I am store images under the assets folder.

Comment: @AhsanAli I am already try this, this is not working on scss property.

Comment: Whether the assets folder is placed in the public folder?